# Get attachments only for this post

Tags: posts, attachments

I have the following code:

```
      <?php
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          if(get_the_title() == 'Archive') query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=1');
          $category = get_the_category();
          if ($category[0]->name) echo '<h1>'.$category[0]->name.'</h1>';

           $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
           foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ): 
           $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
            echo $image."<br />";
           endforeach;

          the_content();
      endwhile;
     ?>
      <?php edit_post_link('Click here in order to edit this page'); ?>
        </div><!--END /.text-->
```

This code is in `page.php` where by default I list a post.I want to get the attachements only for that post `query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=1');` now it also get the attachements  for the page., how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this using the get_children function:

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);
$attachments = get_children($args);
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your code is,
you are trying to get the attachment from the particular post,

it can be easily done using query_post,

```
query_posts( 'attachment_id=5' )
```

where '5' is the post ID

Comment: Well it's not that easy because I don't know the id since i'm querying to display that post

Comment: then get the post id first,   
$pID = get_the_id();
query_posts( "attachment_id='$pID'" );

Comment: query_posts should only be used on the main query. Use a new WP_Query object instead.